# how can I see the values of RS232

Tags: testing, serial-port

I've got a device which works with RS233 and a software which receives the values from device and send it some feed back trough the RS232, so I need to know what's the exact value re instead between this software and device. is there any software to see whats the value ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some software here:
http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/

Also search the net for "serial port snooping", "serial port analyzer"

Comment: that's a good software for serial monitoring, thank you! the next question is : Is it possible to develop a software which works between device and software to receive values from that software and make a change on them, then send the new values to device? which programing language do u suggest for that?